# In my post req of comment, I want to update the values of reviews which consist of userid and comments

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to update my Event. The Event Schema is shown below. How can I push the values as I desire? I am new to this. So, facing some difficulties. Thanks in advance. I want to post it in that id whose id matches and update the comment section as well as userid.

**server.js**

```
var express= require('express');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var config=require('./config');
var app= express();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var lodash= require('lodash');
var underscore= require('underscore');
//var User=require('./database/user')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db',function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("connected!");
    }
});
//res.json({message:"     " })
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true })); //if false then parse only strings
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));//log all the requests to the console
var api=require('./app/routes/api')(app,express,underscore,lodash);
app.use('/api',api);
app.get('*',function(req,res){
  //  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});   // * means any route

app.listen(config.port,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("The server is running");
    }
});
```

**api.js**

```
var User= require('../models/user');
var Event=require('../models/event');
var config=require('../../config');

var secret=config.secretKey;
module.exports=function(app,express,underscore,lodash) {
    var api = express.Router();
    // app.use()

    api.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
        var user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password

        });

        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json({
                message: 'User created!'
            });
        });

    });
    api.get('/users', function (req, res) {
        User.find({}, function (err, users) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
           res.json(users);
        });
    });
    api.post('/eventfeed', function (req, res) {
        var event = new Event({
            name: req.body.name,
            location: req.body.location,
            description: req.body.description,
            price: req.body.price,
            rating: req.body.rating
        });

        event.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json({
                message: 'Event created!'
            });
        });
    });
    api.get('/event', function (req, res) {
        Event.find({}, function (err, event) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json(event);
        });
    });


 api.post('/comment',function(req,res,com){
    User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.id },
        { $push: { userid:req.body.id,comment: req.body.favourite }},
         res.json(com)) ;
});
    return api;
}
```

**event.js**

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var  EventSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    location: String,
    description:String,
    price: Number,
    rating: Number,
    reviews:[{userid:String,
              comment: [String]}]

});
module.exports= mongoose.model('Event',EventSchema);
```

Comment: I'm suspicious of if(err) return err;  I wonder if maybe req.body doesn't contain what you would hope, and maybe you're getting an error from User.update?

Comment: Why is it showing error on User.update?

Comment: Specifically, I don't know - I would recommend at a minimum that you console.log(err) go from there.  Also, maybe /addfavorites is not even being called?  I'd log in both callbacks, and go from there.

Comment: How to update the values in an array favorites[] without overwriting?

Answer (score 0):

In your "addfavorites" controller, use "$push" instead of "$set". This let's you add something to an array in the database, just like the usual push function on Arrays.

Look e.g. here for an example: http://blog.ocliw.com/2012/11/25/mongoose-add-to-an-existing-array/

(There are some extra options "safe: true" etc. you can use to make extra sure there is no overriding).

Comment: Still being over written

Answer (score 0):

You are missing curly braces of `$push`

So,

```
   api.post('/addfavourites', function(req, res) {
            // _id: req.body.id;
            User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.id },
              { $push: { favourites: req.body.favourite }},
              { upsert: true },
                function(fav) { res.json(fav); });
          });
```

It should work now.
*BTW i also found some missing brackets in your code.*

[Link to Syntax Specification](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

Comment: Thanks. I will take care from now :)

Comment: Yes. One thing I want to know is if my JSON is suppose if this type               [{ name : String, reviews:[{userid:String,
                                    comment: [String]}]    }]
 How am I supposed to push the values got into the comment?

Comment: Can you see the ques again please?

Comment: What is `com` in this `api.post('/comment',function(req,res,com)`